# Git push to heroku error: Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, stack-trace

I have googled extensively on this and seen many instances of the above error.

This could be caused by any/many things, and what I've seen is that the cause most likely could be found in the trace.

However, I don't know what could be causing my own error, even from the trace.

The thing I noticed, however, is the line:

```
SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

Which to my understanding has to do with failure in connecting to a resource online. What this resource is in this case, I have no idea.

> PS: this has been working on previous pushes. (Previous pushes to this repo has been with no glitch)

Below is the portion of my log trace showing the error.

```
remote:        Bundle completed (61.86s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:152:in `getaddrinfo'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:152:in `connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:211:in `connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:322:in `establish_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:94:in `block in connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:279:in `with_reconnect'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:93:in `connect'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:350:in `ensure_connected'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:207:in `block in process'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:292:in `logging'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:206:in `process'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:112:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:1320:in `block in smembers'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:37:in `block in synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:37:in `synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:1319:in `smembers'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/flipper-redis-0.7.0/lib/flipper/adapters/redis.rb:26:in `features'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/flipper-0.7.0/lib/flipper/adapters/instrumented.rb:36:in `block in features'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/flipper-0.7.0/lib/flipper/instrumenters/noop.rb:5:in `instrument'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/flipper-0.7.0/lib/flipper/adapters/instrumented.rb:35:in `features'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/flipper-0.7.0/lib/flipper/adapters/memoizable.rb:28:in `features'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/flipper-0.7.0/lib/flipper/dsl.rb:230:in `features
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/config/initializers/flipper.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to oge-resilience-staging.
remote: 
To git@heroku.com:*****'
 ! [remote rejected] dev -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:*****'
```

## flipper.rb

```
require 'flipper/adapters/redis'

flipper_redis_options = {}
flipper_redis_options[:url] = ENV['BOXEN_REDIS_URL'] || ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL']
flipper_redis_client = Redis.new(flipper_redis_options)
flipper_adapter = Flipper::Adapters::Redis.new(flipper_redis_client)

FLIPPER = Flipper.new(flipper_adapter)

unless FLIPPER.features.to_a.detect{|feature| feature.name == "resilience_enabled" }
  FLIPPER[:resilience_enabled].disable
end
```

I will like to understand what the problem is here, and how to go about it. Thanks.

Comment: What code do you have in config/initializers/flipper.rb? In particular on line 10.

Comment: updated question with my `config/initializers/flipper.rb?` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
remote:        SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:152:in `getaddrinfo'
```

It looks like your app is trying to connect to Redis in the following initializer

```
remote:        /tmp/build_96c4b997594af6741a41839fe335a90a/config/initializers/flipper.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
```

but the Redis server is not available (or invalid).

Comment: Okay, thanks. so in this case, what will be the way-forward?

Comment: You need to fix the connection configuration and make sure you are using a valid Redis instance.

Comment: The problem within your configuration may very well be that neither of the environment variables: `ENV['BOXEN_REDIS_URL']` or `ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL']` are set on your heroku server.